# Reading multiple bits using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a simple code that reads values entered by a user:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.printf("Enter with values: ");

String symbol = scanner.next();
System.out.println(symbol);
// But now I only have a single value
```

However I would like to get all the entered values, not just some. The input could be

```
01
// or
01011
// or
000000000000000000000001110
```

The user can enter whatever value he wants. And I want to have an array which contains each of the individual entered bits.

Example array:

```
String[] entries;
entries [0] = "0";
entries [1] = "1";
...
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: use a `List` instead or an array, also use `nextLine` instead of `next`

Comment: I think what you need is a loop. But if you want to store in an array, you'll need to know how many elements will be entered in advance. If you want no limit, use a `List` instead.

Comment: Use `nextLine()` to read the **full** input. Then get a char-array of the `String` entered. Done. You can also do some validation or go from `char` to `int` if you like, but you now already have an array with each character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get continuous input through scanner you can use `scanner.hasNext()` and then store in some array or list. Later depending on some condition you can quit the user inputs from command line. For e.g check below code :

```
public class ScannerTry {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter with values: ");
    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String symbol = scanner.next();
        if(symbol.equals("exit")){
            break;
        }
        entries.add(symbol);
    }
    System.out.println(entries);
}
}
```

**entries** list has all the inputs provided by user till now.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

Use `Scanner#nextLine` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to read the full input, not just a single token. Then call `String#toCharArray` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())) on the resulting `String`. You then have a `char[]` containing all the characters.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
char[] values = input.toCharArray();
```

---

### Validate and `int[]`

If you would like to validate the input (only `0` and `1`) and maybe also rather prefer an `int[]` instead of a `char[]`, just loop over the individual characters, validate and collect them.

In that case you should prefer `String#charAt` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))) to avoid the additional copy induced by `String#toCharArray`.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
int[] values = new int[input.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (c != '0' && c != '1') {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only 1 and 0 are allowed!");
    }
    values[i] = (int) c;
}
```